# I cant see references between Calls and methods in LUA language

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, lua

Hello guys if i use c# in visual studio i can see references nicely like this:
[image]

Is here some way how can i achieve this in VS or VS Code in LUA language?
I tried download LUA packages to both VS and VS code but still cant see anything.

Comment: Use EmmyLua may help.
https://github.com/EmmyLua/VSCode-EmmyLua

Comment: Check class and method accessibility.

Comment: @Martin Ma yes I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a Lua language server, for example https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sumneko.lua

[image]